# How to match a string in URI with regular expression?

Tags: regex, apache

In my Apache config httpd.conf, I wish to setup a rule like below

```
SetEnvIfNoCase %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(getBook+)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

I am hoping to do no-gzip when my URL looks like

http://myurl.fake.com/book/getBook3?id=234 
http://myurl.fake.com/book/getBook1?id=xxx

I am not sure if I can do that by setting up something like the above in httpd.conf..

Thanks!

Comment: The reason I do query string is because the url http://myurl.fake.com/book/getBook3 was mod_rewrite from http://myurl.fake.com/index.php?controller=book&action=getBook3

Comment: I suppose a better place to ask this question would be on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: A rule like that should work I think - however, you need to change your regex to something like this: `^.*(getBook.+)$`

Comment: Thanks, I have changed to SetEnvIfNoCase %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(getBook.+)$ no-gzip dont-vary, but it doesn't work.